# iOS error reading from input stream

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a function which reads bytes from network input stream using

```
long count = [inputstream read:buffer maxlength:no_of_bytes_to_read];
```

I m calling this function two times. first time it is working but for second time my buffer has some unreadable characters at end replacing my original data.

but when i put a breakpoint over this reading function and step over slowly then it reads the accurate data
what may be the reason??

Comment: `What class is this?`

what do you mean?

Comment: You say "input stream" but what is the name of the class.  I could google and work it out, but I shouldn't have to.  Please update your question (and possibly tags).

Comment: if you mean class of inputstream then its 'NSInputStream'

Comment: You should add it to the question to make it more complete.